# NServiceBus throwing stackoverflow while scanning

Tags: nservicebus

Ran into this problem when I moved my message type objects into a different assembly.  For some reason I had no problems when messages and handlers existed in the same project.

NServiceBus throws a StackoverflowException when it scans for assemblies.  This is how I am configuring NServiceBus currently:

```
var bus = NServiceBus.Configure
            .With(AllAssemblies.Matching("Presentation"))
            .DefineEndpointName("Presentation")
            .StructureMapBuilder()
            .Log4Net()
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Demo") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"))
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Demo") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"))
            .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Demo") && (t.Namespace.EndsWith("Messages") || t.Namespace.EndsWith("Queries")))
            .UnicastBus()
            .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
            .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
            .InMemoryFaultManagement()
            .InMemorySagaPersister()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

It overflows in NServiceBus.Configure.GetAllowedTypes, from what I can tell it scans my 3 Presentation projects (Presentation, Presentation.Inventory, and Presentation.Inventory.Messages) just fine, then the method is run again to scan NServiceBus.Core which causes the overflow.

My project structure as it exists currently is here: https://github.com/volak/DDD.Enterprise.Example

Using NServiceBus 4.6.3

I also found that structuremap's assembly scanner is throwing a stackoverflow if I allow it to scan NServiceBus.Core - perhaps this is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tracked the problem back to Fody.Costura specifically this issue https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/48

They suggest that assembly redirects are causing an infinite loop in different versions of assemblies not managed by Costura.  NServiceBus uses Fody quite a bit so I tried removing all assembly redirects in web.config and the thing booted up just fine.

So if you are having this issue you are probably referencing 2 different versions of some assembly, you should fix that before removing all redirects.

For me the problem was both Raven.Client.Lightweight and Raven.Abstractions

I am thinking that NServiceBus probably weaves these assemblies into it's DLL and I am also using them from nuget

Comment: PSA - keep your redirects clean!

Comment: For me it happened in my Test project for NServicebus. I removed the whole <runtime> node in App.config and I worked. Thanks!

Comment: For me this only occurred when in Release mode.